# How do I send a message to a specific channel on a specific message in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord

```js
client.on('message', function(message) {
 if (message.content === 'msg-1')
client.channels.cache.get('Channel_id').send('msg-2')
 }
});
```

How to make the code send a specific message on a specific message in node.js I tried the code above but it don't work this is my first code in node.js so there could be silly mistakes thanks in advance for the answer

Answer (score 0):

You put an additional quirly bracket

So the code needs to be like this:

```js
client.on('message', function(message) {
 if (message.content === 'msg-1')
      client.channels.cache.get('Channel_id').send('msg-2')
});
```